# div overflow right

Tags: css, html, overflow

Is there away to change the default behavior of a div so that overflow:hidden causes the content to overflow out the right side of a div, rather than out of the bottom of the div?

Comment: look at how to use overflow-x and overflow-y in CSS.

Comment: @Diodeus Those properties have nothing to do with his problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `white-space:nowrap`. That way the content won't wrap to a new line.

```
div{
    overflow:hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you!  Exactly what I needed.  Thanks so much.  (I can't up-vote yet because I don't have a high enough reputation.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Have the text not wrap:

```
<div style="width:100px;height:30px; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;">
    Is there away to change the default behavior of a div so that
    overflow:hidden causes the content to overflow out the right side
    of a div, rather than out of the bottom of the div?
</div>
```